# Unable to import adfuller from statsmodels.tsa.stattools

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

I am unable to import adfuller from statsmodels.tsa.stattools

I am getting an Attribute error.

**AttributeError**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4s8.jpg) : module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'

Current pandas version using (1.2.3)

Comment: Your statsmodels is quite old.  You should upgrade to 0.12.2. `pip install statsmodels --upgrade` should work.

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Post it as text.